# Json encoded dict in python and map in golang not matching

Tags: python, json, go

I am generating a HMAC, sha256 hash of a json encoded python dict using json. Lets call it hash1. This is my signature which am sending with JWT. Then I would like to verify this signature at another service in Go. I am using the data that i have in a map(same as python dict), json encoding and hashing it(hash2)
However, hash1 and hash2 are different.
I learned that this is due to python json adding space between elements in dict. Golang json library doesn't add any space.
Is there a way I can work around this?

```py
some_data = {'a':1, 'b':2}
json_str1 = json.dumps(some_data, sort_keys=True)
```

```
some_data := map[string]int{"a":1, "b":2}
json_str2 = json.Marshal(some_data)
```

**EDIT**:
As suggested in one of the answers, using separators in json.dumps would solve the problem. Unfortunately,
I do not own the python side code, so can't do the changes there.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say anything about Go, but when i was generating hash in javascript i had the same issue. You need to play around a bit with separators, maybe something like `json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')`
will work.

Comment: This was helpful. Unfornately, I do not own the python side code. So not able to remove the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`json.Marshal` does not stringify. It rather return the json encoding in bytes.

If you want the string conversion, you can use the following.

```
b, _ := json.Marshal(some_data)
json_str2 := str(b)
```

Since `json.dumps` add an extra space between the field value, you can use the following to add an extra space to the json stringified

```
str := string(b)

fmt.Println(str)
c := strings.Join(strings.Split(str, ","), ", ")
fmt.Println(c)
```

Using this delimiter might fail in case there are strings value with comma `","`.

To make sure not to add any space to strings containing comma, one can use [marshalIndent](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go?s=6964:7036#L166)

```
data, err := json.MarshalIndent(some_data, "", "delimiter")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))

s := strings.Replace(string(data), "\ndelimiter", " ", -1)
s = strings.Replace(s, "{ ", "{", -1) 
s = strings.Replace(s, "\n}", "}", -1)
```

Python output

```
json_str1 = json.dumps(some_data, sort_keys=True)


{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

[Go output](https://play.golang.org/p/B-wFAD1thPe)

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json library in golang has a MarshalIndent function that solves this issue.